# how to match android device of player with the device name in android benchmark data?

Tags: performance, game-development, unreal-engine4

I am developing a game using Unreal, and I need to determine during gameplay whether the performance of the player's Android device is sufficient to handle specific graphic quality. Currently, I am using the GPU to determine which quality should use, but some devices with the same GPU have significant performance differences. Therefore, I want to use the AndroidBenchMark data from PassMark to assess the scores of various devices. However, the device names used in PassMark are not the device model, so it is difficult for me to match the player's device with the devices in the AndroidBenchMark data. Does anyone have any good solutions?

I would like to know how to match the player's device with the devices in the AndroidBenchMark data. Or if there is another method to determine the performance level of the player's device without running benchmarktest in runtime.